# sqlite3_step only returning 1 row

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, sqlite

```
if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
NSString *problemName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
[dataSet addObject:problemName];
[problemName release];
}
```

It executes but only once. I have a few rows of data (i double checked the SQL query) but only the first row is being returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep calling sqlite3_step until it tells you there are no more rows.